# Invoking a JS function defined in Component Template from Angular2

Tags: angular

This is the JS code which needs to be called after Map Component in loaded by Angular2. Code is defined in the Component Template.

```html
<script>
   var x = document.getElementById("demo");
   function getLocation() {
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
       } else {
           x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
       }
   }

   function showPosition(position) {
       x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
       "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
   }

   function showError(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                break;          
        }   
    }
</script>
```

How do i call `getLocation()` function from the component in the `onNgInit` method? (or can this be designed in a better way if possible?)

**Final solution from accepted answer and other SO answers:**

[Working Code In Plunker - integrating Geolocation, angular2-google-maps and Angular2 (RC1)](http://plnkr.co/edit/2FqQri837V2h475KYvL0?p=preview)

Comment: Why don't you move your code inside Angular?

Comment: The code is using the HTML `geolocation` API...I don't see how it can be moved inside the component...

Comment: I don't see what's the problem ;-). You can do everything inside Angular that you can do outside. Except maybe it's a timing issue that it must be done before Angular is finished loading.

Comment: You mean i can paste the `getLocation` function inside the component class and call it on a lifecycle hook?

Comment: Sure. Use `declare` to tell the TypeScript compiler it should assume the name exists (see my updated answer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Using declare in the `component.ts` file while loading it is giving an error: `ReferenceError: declare is not defined`

Comment: In Plunker you don't need `declare` at all. (see my updated answer) To silence compiler warnings use `declare var navigator` - sorry forgot `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add at the end of the script

```
window.myGetLocation = getLocation;
```

In the Angular component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(window.myGetLocation());
}
```

If you add

```
declare var navigator;
```

to your typescript script file you can use `navigator.geolocation...` inside your Angular2 component.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MibG8xV3PjkMmGD8KDC9?p=preview)